# How to solve Linear ODEs system using matrix method in Maple?

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

```
x=[-4 -2; 3 1] [x y] + [-t -2t-1]
x(0)=[3 -5]
```

As I know firstly, when the matrix is denoted by `A`, we must compute `exp(At)` by diagonalizing `A`: if `A=PDP^(-1)` for a diagonal `D` then `exp(At) = P exp(Dt) P^(-1)` where `exp(Dt)` is a diagonal matrix with `(exp(Dt))_{ii} = exp(D_(ii) t)`...

How can I write The Maple code? ( Sorry, I write in here since I didn't find maple.stackexchange)

```
restart: with(LinearAlgebra):

A := Matrix(2,2,[-4,-2,3,1]);
```

....

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is the correct place to ask such question on the Stack Exchange network. However, your code is not very easily interpretable and I do not understand your first line of code; specifically you use `x` as something that is both two- and one-dimensional. Nevertheless, if you are interested in solving the system with `P` and `D`, you can retrieve these by `E,P :=LinearAlgebra:-Eigenvectors(A);` and then `myD := LinearAlgebra:-DiagonalMatrix(E);`.

Comment: Alternatively, the `dsolve` functional can also handle linear systems of ODEs.